# Use LINQ where list of items contains any component in a list of components

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ, how can I find a list of items where it's list of components contains a component from another list of components?

Structure:

```
class Item
{
    public List<Component> Components {get;set;}
}

class Component
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Example:

```
var components = new List<string> { "C1", "C2" , "C3" }
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item("IT1")
    {
        Components = new List<Component> { "C1", "C4","C5" }                    
    },
    new Item("IT2")
    {
        Components = new List<Component> { "C6", "C7","C8" }
    },
    new Item("IT3")
    {
        Components = new List<Component> { "C2", "C0","C9" }
    }
}
```

The output will returns items IT1 and IT3.

I tried the following:

```
items
    .Select(i => i.Components)
    .Where(c => components.Contains(c.Any(x => x.Name.ToString()));
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the other way around: first the `Any` and then the `Contains`.  You would like to get all items that have *any* of there components *contained* in the `components` list.

Also don't use the `Select` if you'd like to get a list of `Item` back:

```
var result = items.Where(i => i.Components.Any(c => components.Contains(c.Name)));
```

Answer (score 3):

It because `Any` expects boolean value, but you return string: `x.Name.ToString`.

You can check intersection of two sequences in you case:

```
items.Where(x => x.Components.Intersect(components).Any())
```

`Intersect` will return non-empty sequence, if both `item.Components` and `components` contain same elements. Then `Any` without parameters will return `true`, if the sequence is non-empty.